# SQL Server - To find member with the highest fine charged (based on below scenario)

Tags: sql-server-2008

i have a scenario where there are 2 tables
tblMember with 2 columns MemberID & MemberName

```
100  Aakash
101  Seema
```

tblLoanHistory with columns LoanID, MemberID, FineCharged

```
1   100   30
2   100   60
3   101   30
```

I want to find the member whose total fine charged is highest.

output should be

```
100   Aakash   90   (60+30=90)
```

can anybody please help

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT TOP 1
   M.MemberID, M.MemberName,
   SUM(LH.FineCharged)
FROM
   tblMember  M
   JOIN
   tblLoanHistory LH ON LH.MemberID=M.MemberID 
GROUP BY
   M.MemberID, M.MemberName
ORDER BY
   SUM(LH.FineCharged) DESC
```

Update... Oops! Added JOIN condition

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT M.MemberID ,M.MemberName,SUM(LH.FineCharged) FineCharged
FROM tblMember M
INNER JOIN tblLoanHistory LH ON LH.MemberID=M.MemberID 
GROUP BY M.MemberID, M.MemberName
```

Comment: the above query only gives total fine charged for all members. What i want is the member who paid the highest fine. I guess this can be obtained by adding [top 1] and [order by -desc] as answered by @gbn in the above reply. SELECT ***top 1*** M.MemberID ,M.MemberName,SUM(LH.FineCharged) FineCharged FROM tblMember M INNER JOIN tblLoanHistory LH ON LH.MemberID=M.MemberID GROUP BY M.MemberID, M.MemberName ***order by FineCharged desc***